# Software Abstractions Book model: Visualize a separate graph per Book

Tags: alloy

**UPDATE:** I have stumbled upon these [slides](http://www.sts.tu-harburg.de/teaching/ws-07.08/LTOOAD/09-alloy-dynamic.pdf) which appear to show (on pg 22) how to achieve the projection I want.  However, I cannot see how the screenshots correspond to the GUI I am using: I only have a *projection button* not a configuration panel.  Incidentally, I am running Alloy 4.2 on Ubuntu Linux.

On page 7 of the *Software Abstractions* book (revised edition), the author states:

> I have instructed the analyzer to "project" the instance on Book, which means that it shows a separate graph for each book object.

Figure 2.1 shows such a graph particular to Book_0.

The visualizer has a button: *Projection* which - when clicked - offers a list of checkboxes (one per signature).  When I check *Book*, the graph in the visualizer changes from this:

[image: projection-none]

to this:

[image: projection-book]

which is nothing like the figures in Software Abstractions.

As far as I can see, the *projection button* is the *only* way I can alter the projection: the slides I found online show a GUI with more configuration options, but I can't see them anywhere.  Am I missing something?

How can I visualize one Book at a time, as per the figures in chapter 2?

Comment: Are you using the example from page 6? It doesn't have groups.

Comment: Well spotted! The graph above is from section 2.4. Still doesn’t look like the book figures, though.

Comment: Just to clarify, this is different from using the arrows at the bottom of the visualizer, after you've projected, right?

Comment: There are no arrows at the bottom of my visualizer. I think that’s what I’m missing.